# KeyStore doesn't return correct key

Tags: java, android, aes, keystore

I'm trying to store AES secret key inside Android KeyStore:

```
        String alias = "alias7";

        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
        keyStore.load(null);

        KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES);
        keyGenerator.init(256);
        SecretKey secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();

        if (!keyStore.containsAlias(alias)) {
            keyStore.setEntry(
                alias,
                new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(secretKey),
                new KeyProtection.Builder(KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                    .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
                    .build());
        }

        System.out.println(keyStore.getKey(alias, null));

        SecretKey storedSecretKey = ((KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry(alias, null)).getSecretKey();

        System.out.println(secretKey.toString());
        System.out.println(secretKey.getAlgorithm());
        System.out.println(secretKey.getEncoded().length);

        System.out.println('-');

        System.out.println(storedSecretKey.toString());
        System.out.println(storedSecretKey.getAlgorithm());
        System.out.println(storedSecretKey.getEncoded().length);
```

In the logs I have:

> I/System.out: android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreSecretKey@51abbd87
>
> I/System.out: javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@fffe879c
>
> I/System.out: AES
>
> I/System.out: 32
>
> I/System.out: -
>
> I/System.out: android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreSecretKey@51abbd87
>
> I/System.out: AES

The last System.out.println() doesn't return "32" - it throws an error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array

Why?

Answer (score 2):

Keys stored in AndroidKeyStore are non-extractable, so any attempt to get the key content, such as `secretKey.getEncoded()` on a stored key must fail.

It is a security measure of AndroidKeyStore. The keys can be used but the keying material is not exposed.